# Angular 6 description in interface properties

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to ask if its possible to ad description attribute to property, some equivalent of dot net data descriptions, for example:

```
interface ModuleStatus {
    [Description "Module state"]
    moduleStateSymbol: string;
    [Description "Module type"]
    moduleTypeSymbol: string;
}
```

It would give me some dynamic in html, something like:

```
<pre>{{moduleStatus.getDescription}} - {{moduleStatus.moduleStateSymbol}}</pre>
```

Is it possible??
And if not in interface i can change it to class??

Answer (score 1):

no its not possible . interface are just for type checking and doesnt exist in runtime .

instead u can use es6 class and use decorators to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Soroush_Neshat's comment:

An interface is just a Type safety thing, it doesn't actually have any content in it. You can use it to tell other classes that a certain functionality is provided in the class.

For example:

```js
interface ISomeInterfaceName {
  statusMessage: string;
  description: string;
}

// This will be in in your component

system: ISomeInterfaceName = {
  statusMessage: "OK",
  description: "This is amazing, the status is OK"
}
```

```html
<span>The status is {{system.statusMessage}} - {{system.description}}</span>
```

So you can use the interface to make sure the system variable has certain properties. Then in your template, you can call the variable with the properties.